# Will CLUSTER cluster the index in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, clustered-index

Will CLUSTER in PostgreSQL also arrange the index itself in an efficient way on the disk? Or is this of little relevance? I mostly have index-only scans on queries where performance matter and I wonder if clustering is irrelevant then.

Answer (score 0):

[CLUSTER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-cluster.html) rewrites the table using an index order but does not rewrite any index.

Comment: So then you could delete the index afterwards with no negative effects (if it's only used for clustering purposes of course)? Why are the index(es) not rearranged as well? It can't be uncommon with queries that have to load a significant fraction of an index. The reason I wondered this in the first place is that I see significant improvement in speed also for index-only scans, but that doesn't fit with the documentation (which only talks about the table).

Comment: Clustering a table means ordering the rows in the table according to their ordering in the index. In a index keys are always sorted: there is no need to sort again the index.

Comment: CLUSTER doc says about performance: "if you tend to access some data more than others, and there is an index that groups them together, you will benefit from using CLUSTER. If you are requesting a range of indexed values from a table, or a single indexed value that has multiple rows that match, CLUSTER will help because once the index identifies the table page for the first row that matches, all other rows that match are probably already on the same table page, and so you save disk accesses and speed up the query.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't apply to index-only scans. Is an index always sorted _on disk_?

Comment: OK: for index-only scans clustering the table is not needed. And yes, a btree index is always sorted on disk,

Comment: I cannot explain why clustering the table can improve the performance of index-only scans. If you can reproduce this, please post a "minimal reproducible example" with EXPLAIN ANALYZE output of the queries.